# Get returned value from json_decode output

Tags: php, json

so take this as the url output from the browser.

```
{
 "data": {
  "detections": [
   [
    {
     "language": "en",
     "isReliable": false,
     "confidence": 0.5714286
    }
   ]
  ]
 }
}
```

now i need to get "en" value from the returned values
i tried:

```
$from = $json->data->detections->language;
```

still none work. what am i missing here ?

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($detect));
```

Comment: print_r/var_dump are your friends

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is

```
$json->data->detections[0][0]->language;
```

Get `var_dump($json);` and see the actual structure